# KFAS and dlm packages in R

Tags: r, install.packages

I am using R studio and am trying to install the KFAS and dlm packages by using install.packages("KFAS") and install.packages("dlm") to use them for state space models however the below error is being prompted:

> installed.packages("dlm")
>        Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances
>        License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum
>        NeedsCompilation Built
>   installed.packages("KFAS")
>        Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances
>        License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum
>        NeedsCompilation Built

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message shows you have used installed.packages("dlm") and installed.packages("KFAS") which returns information about available packages.

To download and install a package, you should use install.packages:

```
install.packages("dlm")
install.packages("KFAS")
```